# Why does InDesign only return the field name when I data merge multiple records on a master page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page, data-merge

I'm trying to data merge multiple records on a page. The single record per page works fine.

[image]

But when I try for multiple records through the master page I get this:

[image]

**Why is InDesign displaying the field name instead the values I expect, when I try to data merge on a master page?**

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without seeing a screenshot of your CSV file and the Data-Merge window. Something has to be wrong with one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Data Merge works only with document pages. When you put a field on a Master Page, you get the result you're seeing.

The Master Page should contain only elements that don't change (background images, static text, and so on).

Your document page is where you place the fields that InDesign will populate with data from the merge.